# React + Jest: Test that setTimeOut didn't get called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, settimeout, use-effect, react-testing-library

I currently have a `setTimeOut` inside a `useEffect`, I was able to test it by using:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
```

And it works great. However, the setTimeout is getting triggered a few times as `successMessage` changes. How can I write a test that checks that `setTimeOut` is only called when `successMessage` is not an empty string?

I'm using jest and react-testing-library.

Here is my react code.

```
enum HELPER_MESSAGES {
    SUCCESS = 'Congratulations you signed up!',
    ERROR = 'Email address invalid',
}

export function EmailCapture (): ReactElement {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>('');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<string>('');
    const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState<string>('');

    function handleOnClick (): void {
        const EMAIL_REGEX: RegExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-._][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*.)+\.+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
        const isInputValid: boolean = EMAIL_REGEX.test(inputValue) && inputValue !== '';

        if (isInputValid) {
            setSuccessMessage(HELPER_MESSAGES.SUCCESS);
        } else {
            setErrorMessage(HELPER_MESSAGES.ERROR);
        }
    }

    useEffect((): () => void => {
        const resetAfterSuccessTimer: NodeJS.Timeout = setTimeout((): void => {
            setSuccessMessage('');
        }, 5000);

        return (): void => {
            clearTimeout(resetAfterSuccessTimer);
        };
    }, [successMessage]);

    function handleOnChange (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
        setErrorMessage('');
        setSuccessMessage('');
    }

    return (
        <TextInput
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            error={errorMessage}
            success={successMessage}
            value={inputValue}
        />
    );
}
```

I'm following TDD, so I'm looking to write a test that will make me write the following code:

```
useEffect((): () => void => {
    let resetAfterSuccessTimer: NodeJS.Timeout;

    if (successMessage) {
        resetAfterSuccessTimer= setTimeout((): void => {
            setSuccessMessage('');
            setButtonText('Sign up!');
            console.log('sexy');
        }, 5000);
    }

    return (): void => {
        clearTimeout(resetAfterSuccessTimer);
    };
}, [successMessage]);
```

The `sexy` word should only get console logged once.

Comment: after instantiating, it shouldn't be called. after a successMessage it should be called once and since it changes successMessage it calls useEffect but it don't call setTimeout... I believe thats about it...

Comment: @Noriller I'm not sure if I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out based on their documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks , you can just do the following:

```
expect(setTimeout).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

And when you want to check that it got called once, you can do:

```
expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Note: This is testing an implementation detail, so be aware of that.